# Windows 7 has no internet connection after driver install

Tags: windows-7, connection

I have **windows 7** on my laptop. It has had an Internet connection for weeks.

I installed a WACOM art pen **driver** which was for Vista.

After rebooting, I have **no Internet** connection (It just says: "Unidentified network, No network access")

My **desk** computer is still online.

I have tried connecting the network **cable** which works in my desk computer, but it doesn't get laptop/win7 online.

I **uninstalled** the WACOM tablet pen driver and rebooted, but it is still offline.

**How can I get Windows 7 back online?**

[image]

Comment: whats your router IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past when having strange issues with network connectivity a full reload of them via a reboot often resolves the issue.

Uninstall and re-install the network interface device drivers (wireless and/or wired).

Do this via Device Manager > Network Adapters > Right click 'Uninstall'.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have many causes. 
If the method proposed by Nick Josevski doesn't work, see this article : ["Unidentified Network or 'Local Only' Network"](http://lazytechs.com/viewarticle.php?id=19&cat=2) that lists several more proposals, too many for me to list here.